# Create a mat file

Tags: matlab, mat

I saw the next tutorial: https://www.mathworks.com/videos/object-recognition-deep-learning-and-machine-learning-for-computer-vision-121144.html.

At the Demo 2 was doing with deep learning a food detection. For this was use a .mat file. 
I want to use the code for road sign detection but I don't know how to create my .mat file. 
I have 25 images for input and I want to do a .mat file.
I searched on Internet and I found the following code.

```
%Generate mat file
srcFile = dir('..\ROAD-SIGN\*.jpg')
result = cell(1,length(srcFile))
for i = 1 : length(srcFile)
    filename = strcat('...\ROAD-SIGN\',srcFile(i).name)
    I = imread(filename);
    %figure, imshow(I);
    I = imresize(I,[273 273]);
    result{i} = I;  
    %figure, imshow(result{i});
end
save images1.mat, result;
length(srcFile)
load('images1.mat')
for j = 1:length(srcFile)
    figure, imshow(result{j});
end
%Read mat file 
for j =1 :length(srcFile)
    filename = strcat('...\ROAD-SIGN\',srcFile(j).name);
    I = imread(filename);
    a='I';
    input = load('images1.mat',a);
    figure, imshow(input.(a));
end
whos -file images1.mat
```

But it isn't working because in the main program is useing the layer attributt. In my code for a .mat file I don't have the layer attribute.

Can anyone help me with a solution, please?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zeF8t.jpg)

Comment: Use the [`save`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/save.html) function to save files as .mat

Comment: I tryed the save command but isn,t working

Answer (score 0):

To create a mat file with certain variables from your workspace, you should be able to use:

> > `save('matfilename','result');`

The issue is whether you need to create a mat file for this particular example? You already have your images in 'result', do you really need to save them and then load them again?

Also, (hint!) check out [ImageDatastore](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.io.datastore.imagedatastore.html) for easier reading in of your input files.